# android fetching json outside of MainThread

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, request

I need to fetch some data from an external source (a json-source).
The external source is a simple http-response..
The data is supposed to replace some text to be able to localize my app using a CMS.
The I tried running the request inthe mainthread, but for what I understand thats not the way to go.. since its required to run in another thread or async..
The thing I dont get is..
If I refactor my code and make it run in a seperate thread or a asynctask, then isnt it possible for the app to execute all code, display something for the user with out actually have executed and finished the other thread?..
Cause I guess I need to lock the mainthread some where anyway to make sure that the localized textes are displayed.. or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: use asynctask for this purpose. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: In the AsyncClass that you can create, there are several methods (4 to be exact) which serve this purpose. You can choose one place in the Mainthread where you can wait for the result of the separate Thread and collect the result of it.

Comment: Ok thank you :),
I might be stupid.. but isnt waiting for the result in the mainthread the same thing as locking the mainthread by executing the same code directly in the mainthread? The outcome is the same right?... why do we have to do this "round-tripping"?